# How do I set up a "gateway" for a specific subdomain?

Tags: apache, subdomain

I'm looking at setting up a website that will run a few different apps.  Most of them can be managed by an Apache server, but I've got one specific thing that will run on a custom HTTP server.

Looking around on apache.org, it looks like you can use mod_proxy to configure Apache to act as a "reverse proxy" and forward requests from a specific subdirectory to a new server with the ProxyPass directive.  So if I wanted send anything from `mysite.com/special` on to the custom server, that's how I would do it.

But what if I want to set it up as a subdomain instead?  [The documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) doesn't seem to cover that.  If, I wanted to make it forward anything from `special.mysite.com` to the new server, how would I set that up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's only HTTP traffic:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName special.mysite.com
    ProxyRequests     Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8081/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8081/
  <Location />
    Allow from all
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

(This assumes your "special" server runs on 8081. Change that URL to wherever it runs.)